# Nginx define a route as server name

Tags: linux, nginx, server

Consider example.com as my base URL. I have a separated project with routing and I want it to be serving only on one route of my base URL like example.com/a. It means if I call example.com/a/b my separated project receives just /b.
I was thinking about something like this but it's wrong:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com/a;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://project;
    }
}
```

Comment: @jww well I guess I should consider joining there! :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked for me is to implicitly change route but not the URL using rewrite and proxy_pass, but this method will **only works with single page** for example if you are trying to access example.com/a/b this method works but **not working** with example.com/a/b/c:

```
location /a {
    rewrite a / break;
    # proxy pass to localhost address of separated project
    proxy_pass         http://localhost:3000;
    proxy_redirect     off;
    proxy_set_header   Host $host;
}
```